# Back stack fragments limit

Tags: android-fragments

How to make the maximum stack size in 5 fragments. Adding 6 fragment,  1 fragment should be deleted, but quietly, without showing screen.

[Fragment1]->[Fragment2]->[Fragment3]->[Fragment4]->[Fragment5]

Added 6 fragment

<s>[Fragment1]</s>[Fragment2]->[Fragment3]->[Fragment4]->[Fragment5]->[Fragment6]

when the user will come back he will be on 5 screens.

The main problem, how to remove FragmentManager.BackStackEntry from the back stack fragment manager in a quiet, not pushing on the screen.

Is this possible ?

Comment: My question as well .. I guess we need to use own custom stack

Answer (score 0):

The Fragment back stack is indeed a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) where the only available options are:

> - push, which adds an element to the collection, and
> - pop, which removes the most recently added element that was not yet removed.

Therefore removing Fragments from the bottom of the stack is not a supported operation. You'd need to manage your own back stack (by overriding [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) and using [`attach()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#attach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment))/[`detach()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#detach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) operations) to provide this effect.